# Limit of function f

Tags: calculus, limits

When we can do this with limits.

$$\lim_{x \to \ a} [f(x)]^{\frac 1 n} = [f(\lim_{x \to \ a} x)]^{\frac 1 n}$$

Generally when function is continuous we can take limit inside.

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} [f(x)]^{\frac 1 n} = f([\lim_{n \to \infty} x]^{\frac 1 n})$$

Comment: This doesn't make any sense $\lim_{n\to \infty} x=x$ so you're basically saying that $\lim_{n\to\infty}[f(x)]^{1/n}=[f(x)]^{1/n}$ which is absurd since RHS has no limit.

Comment: Sorry , I completely asked a absurd thing. Now I edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you have a continuous function then you can interchange the function with the limit operator.

The function $y \mapsto y^n$ is continuous. Therefore, if $f$ is continuous, so is the function $x \mapsto f(x)^n$.

For continuous $f$ you can therefore write 
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^n = f(\lim_{x \to a} x)^n = f(a)^n.
$$

Comment: Is it also holds for rational and irrational powers?

Comment: It holds for all non-negative powers. If $n<0$, $x \mapsto f(x)^n$ may become discontinuous.